# How to get process memory from both .NET Standard 2.0 and UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I'm working on a small .NET Standard 2.0 [logging library](https://github.com/Sergio0694/BigWatson), and I'm having trouble finding a way to reliably get the memory used by the current process across all platforms, especially on UWP.

Right now I'm using this code (.NET Standard 2.0):

```
long memory = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
```

Which works fine, **but** throws a nice `PlatformNotSupportedException` exception on UWP (actually, that's only in DEBUG mode, while in RELEASE is directly throws a `TypeLoadException` plus a bunch of other P/Invoke exceptions for some reason).

The problem here is that that API is obviously not supported on UWP, where I should use:

```
long memory = (long)MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsage;
```

The problem is that the [MemoryManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.memorymanager) is a UWP-only API, and it is not present in .NET Standard 2.0. Now, the first workaround that comes to mind is to expose a setting in the library to let the user manually set a custom `Func<long>` delegate that retrieves the current memory usage, so that if it knows the default method won't work on the current platform, it'll be possible to override it.

This seems like a bad trick though, and I'd like to keep everything self-contained withing the library instead. So my question is:

> Is there a way to reliably retrieve the current process/app usage across any platform that supports .NET Standard 2.0 libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe* a little dirty, but the following could work (may add some better error handling and such):

```
public static long GetProcessMemory()
{
    try
    {
        return Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
    }
    catch
    {           
        var type = Type.GetType("Windows.System.MemoryManager, Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
        return Convert.ToInt64(type.GetProperty("AppMemoryUsage", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null));
    }
}
```

I use reflection to get around the fact that `MemoryManager` is not available for .NET Standard at compile time, but for the UWP runtime. This way the same assembly would work for both runtimes.
But in general I would prefer a way which generates a fitting assembly per runtime like suggested by Martin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is indeed the approach I ended up using. Your solution doesn't work though (and I don't want to "steal" a valid answer by posting my own code here), if you can edit yours I'll be happy to mark this as valid. You just need to change the type name (it needs the fully qualified assembly name to work) and get rid of the `Activator` call (`MemoryManager` is a static class). Also, you need to add the proper property binding flags (the property is static too) 

Comment: @Sergio0694 Thanks for the update - the old code was "out of my head", now I updated it to a working/tested example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the same trick previously used for Portable Class Libraries - [Bait and Switch](https://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/). It is still [compatible with .NET Standard 2.0](https://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/bait-and-switch-with-net-standard/2668). This way you can create a specific implementation for UWP and fall back to the standard implementation otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure this would be the right approach here, as imho it goes against the whole point of a .NET Standard lib, which is to define platform-agnostic code instead of targeting specific frameworks (I always think of it like something similar to the POSIX standard).
Plus, having an additional .dll just for this single property seems a bit of an overkill here.

Comment: I know, but for platform specific functionality this is still the only option you have... In such case this seems cleaner. But the try catch approach is simpler, although dirtier...

Comment: Yeah I agree using reflections is a bit dirtier, but given that I'm using them in other places in the lib I can live with this solution for now. Let's say I hope a future UWP update will actually implement/support more .NET Standard APIs, with possibly a common API to retrieve the current used memory size. I understand the `Process` class is locked for UWP apps for security reasons, but here we'd just need a "read only" way to check the memory usage, so that seems reasonable.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense and I would actually expect this to work, it is quite surprising it is not implemented